# Unable to contact my local serveur and getting 404 error

Tags: java, server

I have started my server by placing two new jar files , But not able to hit the url and getting 404 error.

Checked the server logs and only native_stderr file is getting generated and it is showing something like below :

```xml
<expansion type="tenured" amount="36243456" newsize="1073741824" timetaken="0.008" 
            reason="excessive time being spent in gc" gctimepercent="17" />

<contraction type="tenured" amount="27274240" newsize="913526784" timetaken="0.000" 
             reason="excess free space following gc" />`
```

But when i reverted the jars application is working fine.

Please suggest what is going wrong.

Comment: which were those jars?

Comment: why is this tagged with garbage-collection? did you place jar or war files

Comment: I have placed Jars files, Which contains my classes files

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan-I have tried to findout the cause of the errors and something related to JVM GC related things. But i was not able to get the relevant information thats why added this in garbage collector.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal-IBM websphere server

Comment: "It works. Then I add jars and it doesn't work. Then I remove them and it works again." My guess is the issue is in the jar files that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Sorry to say but it cant be shared as its related to internal project, Is this not related to server ??

Comment: Please let me know if anything is related to the code which i have attached in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployed the complete setup again, it resolved now. Thanks for all the information and support provided.The new jar was not gettting loaded in the server properly when server was getting started, Because of that it was throwing that error.

enabled the verbose class loader trace to find out the information about the jars.